# The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format - HTTP network

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

code

```
    let session = URLSession.shared

    // prepare json data
    let json: [String: Any] = ["email": "test_mobile@mysite.com"]

    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)

    let proceedURL = NSURL(string:"https://mysitename.herokuapp.com/api/users/isUser")
    //let proceedURL = NSURL(string:"https://google.com")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: proceedURL! as URL)
    //HTTP Headers
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/www.inception.v1", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    request.addValue("Authorization", forHTTPHeaderField: "Basic aW5jZXB0aW9uQGZ1cmRvOmljM=")
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    //request.httpBody = jsonData


    // insert json data to the request
    request.httpBody = jsonData

    //create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

        guard error == nil else {
            return
        }

        guard let data = data else {
            return
        }

        // Print out response string
        let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print("responseString = \(responseString!)")

        do {
            //create json object from data
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: AnyObject] {
                print(json)
                // handle json...
            }

        } catch let error {
            print("error : " + error.localizedDescription)
        }

    })

    task.resume()
```

error :
The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

I am beginner in iphone app development, help me on it and give better suggestion for make network connection (like in android i am using Volley library )

Actual Response is :

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "http_status_code": 200,
  "data": {
    "email": "test_mobile@mysite.com",
    "phone": "8090909000"
  }
}
```

i am using same on Android and test in postmen.

```
// Print out response string
        let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
```

for upper code response is nothing

Comment: Use Alamofire for iOS - Swift

Comment: like in error, data is in wrong format

Comment: Yeah, so what should he do? @Lu_

Comment: if it is not a json, handle data in other way, i don't know what it is, you did not show us anything

Comment: What's the value of `responseString`? Is it JSON valid? Is it really a Dictionary?

Comment: @Larme response i updated in question

Comment: I tested in postman I have a problem in my web service ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Alamofire.

```
let json: [String: Any] = ["email": "test_mobile@mysite.com"]

Alamofire.request(.POST, "https://mysitename.herokuapp.com/api/users/isUser" , parameters: json, encoding:  .JSON).responseJSON {
            Response in
            switch Response.result {
            case .Success(let _data):
                let JsonData = JSON(_data)
                print("JsonData : \(JsonData)")


           //handle json


case .Failure(let _error):
                print(_error)
                let AlertBox = UIAlertController(title: "Connection Failed", message: "No Connection", preferredStyle: .Alert)
                let ActionBox = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok" , style: .Default, handler: { _ in})
                AlertBox.addAction(ActionBox)
                self.presentViewController(AlertBox, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
```

Comment: Alamofire is 3rd party library or native ?

Comment: @Rohit Kumar Kanojia it is third party.

Comment: @TusharSharma thank you , is ios have any official library (just for curiosity In Android there is volley by Google )

Answer (score 0):

```
let json: [String: Any] = ["email": "test_mobile@mysite.com"]

let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)

// create post request
let url = URL(string: "http://httpbin.org/post")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
 request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

// insert json data to the request
request.httpBody = jsonData

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
        return
    }
    let responseJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
    if let responseJSON = responseJSON as? [String: Any] {
        print(responseJSON)
    }
}

task.resume()
```